# How to route openvpn traffic through a second network adapter, to access the internet

Tags: networking, iptables, openvpn, linux-networking, ufw

I am running an ubuntu server with two network adapters eth0 and usb0, both with separate internet connections.
The openvpn server is listening on eth0, and client can connect to the vpn using the public IP of eth0 and access  internet through the VPN. Since i am pushing the default gateway route in openvpn server config file with

```
     push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```

and added the UFW before.rules

```
    # START OPENVPN RULES
    # NAT table rules
    *nat
    :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
    -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
    COMMIT
    # END OPENVPN RULE
```

I was able to route all client internet traffic through the eth0 gateway.

Now I am trying to forward the vpn clients traffic,  which is connected to the VPN, through the eth0 external ip address, to use the usb0 gateway instead of the default eth0 gateway to access the internet. so i have tried changing the UFW POSTROUTING rule to

```
    -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o usb0 -j MASQUERADE
```

But that doesn't seem to work, the traffic is not routed from the tun0 (VPN) interface to the the usb0 interface.

This is what I want my connection to looks like. The client will access the openvpn server using the static public IP of the eth0 adapter. And that traffic should be forwarded to the usb0 gateway to access the internet.

```
    Client(10.8.0.2) --> tun0(VPN adapter, accepting connections on eth0) --> usb0 --> Internet
```

I am sure i am missing the routing rule. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Once you configured your OpenVPN and your clients are able to reach the server, forget that it is a VPN. Threat it as if it is just another NIC.

So, you have a server with three NICs, one LAN (tun0), two WAN. You want to *route* some clients (itself, local processes) via one WAN (eth0) and other clients (those who behind tun0) via another WAN (usb0).

For that, you need a (not very) complicated routing setup, which involves setting two different default routes, both active at the same time. You'll use *routing policy database* (RPDB) for that.

The key is the configuration technique called *split access*, which is described in the [Linux Advanced Routing And Traffic Control HOWTO](https://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html) (aka LARTC). The following is just sligtly adapted copy of that page.

You'll use two additional routing tables. It is better to allocate symbolic aliases for them, which is done in the `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` file:

```
echo "101 eth0_wan" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
echo "102 usb0_wan" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

Now, you certainly have some addresses on your NICs and default routes on WAN NICs, i.e. gateways for each link. You set up default routes each to its own table. Also add default route into main table:

```
ip route add default via ${GW_ETH0} table eth0_wan
ip route add default via ${GW_USB0} table usb0_wan
ip route add default via ${GW_ETH0}
```

You can assume last line was already executed by the `ifupdown`, if you specified `gateway` in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Now make routing rules (policies) that instruct packets with source address of some NIC to go out via that NIC, and also direct OpenVPN users to `usb0`:

```
ip rule add from ${ADDR_ETH0} lookup eth0_wan
ip rule add from ${ADDR_USB0} lookup usb0_wan
ip rule add from ${NETWORK_OPENVPN} lookup usb0_wan
```

These all commands can be added into `/etc/network/interfaces` file `post-up` hook. You don't generally need corresponding default routes removal in the `pre-down` hook, but it'll be cleaner if you do remove routing rules there.

And setup NAT of course, you've done that, but I'll specify here for completeness:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o usb0 -j MASQUERADE
```

(these rules probably need more tight match criteria).